# Include a foreign key column in the table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have the following situation. My table is:

Table: CompanyEmployees

- EmployeeID
- Date of Birth
- Date Joined

I also want to store the sales information for each employee. I have this:

Table: DealsCompleted

- ID
- EmployeeID
- Deal Name
- Deal Amount

My question is this- should there be a column in CompanyEmployees called "DealsCompletedID" which directly refers to the ID column in DealsCompleted, or is it acceptabe to just create a foreign key between the two Employee ID columns? Does this disadvantage the design or potentially distort the normalization?

I am unclear what the rule is as to whether I should include an extra column in CompanyEmployees or not.

**EDIT Please assume there will only be one row in the deal table, per employee.**

Comment: what is the relationship between the two tables? One-to-one? one-to-many? many-to-many?

Comment: Does each employee have many completed deals or does each completed deal have many employees or both?

Comment: Your proposed column wouldn't work for any employee with more than one deal.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect your comments.

Comment: If there is a one-to-one relationship between the tables, maybe there should be just one table?   However, I can't imagine what requirements you are dealing with, given the semantics of your tables, where this would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FOREIGN KEY` should point from one table to its referenced row in a parent table, the two tables should generally not reference each other (with foreign keys defined in both).

The `FOREIGN KEY` is most appropriately defined in the `DealsCompleted` table, which points back to `CompanyEmployees.EmployeeID`.  Think about it this way - The `CompanyEmployees` table stores information *about* employees.  Deals they completed do not really count as information *about employees*.  However, the employee who completed a deal is a part of the information *about a deal*, so the key belongs there.

Having `DealsCompleted.EmployeeID` will allow for a proper one to many relationship between employees and deals. That is, one employee can have as many related rows in `DealsCompleted` as needed. Including a `DealsCompleted` column in the `CompanyEmployees` table on the other hand, would require you to either *duplicate* rows about employees, which breaks normalization, or include *multiple `DealCompletedID` values in one column* which is also incorrect.

**Update after edit above** Even if you plan for only a one-to-one relationship (one deal per employee), it is still more appropriate to reference the `EmployeeID` in `DealsCompleted` rather than the other way around (or both ways).  ...And it allows you to *expand to one-to-many*, when the need arises.

Comment: Does your answer remain the same if the DealsCompleted table only ever stored one row per Employee?

Comment: @user997112 Yes, and I was just adding something about that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the relationship will always be one-to-one, as you state, then the answer depends on what is the *primary* entity within the Domain Model.  If this database is at its core a database about Deals, and employee data is ancillary, then I would add an EmployeeId FK column in the Deal table.  If otoh, this is a database about Employees, and Deals are ancillary, then eliminate the EmployeeId column in the Deal table, and add a DealId FK column to the Employeee table.